# How to change line colors and using SherlockActionBar, SherlockFragment and HoloEverywhere?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I must change collors from my tabs, from my tab indicator, the line between tabs and action bar and the separator tabs.
I've already read something about it, looked around but without any success.
To be clear, the customization that i need to do is that one:

[image]

Which links can i use to customize it like this?
Someone have any example that could help me with?